# amcharts - Adding ticks between categories

Tags: amcharts4

I would like to add ticks between categories on the category axis to separate them, as highlighted in the picture below.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: column chart]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a tutorial [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Positioning_grid_and_labels)

`categoryAxis.renderer.ticks.template.location = 0;`